# Search for mp3 in Shell with Python

Tags: python-3.x, search, mp3

So I'm quite new to Python and I wanted to make a music player. I already have a way for you to choose them in a list, but I wanted to add a search funtion. Is there a way for me to add one in, and how would I go about doing that? I added some .mp3 in the folder with the .py file, but I don't know how I would make the user search for it, make them choose a file and then play it.

Is there anyone experienced enough to help me? [Picture of the main menu for my music player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iC1C.png)

Comment: It is hard to help you without seeing your code. Try to modify your question adding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all mp3 files in any given folder with `pathlib`. Here is an example that lists all mp3s in the current folder, `'.'`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder_path = Path('.')
mp3_paths_generator = folder_path.glob('*.mp3')
mp3_string_paths_generator = map(str, mp3_paths_generator)
print(list(mp3_string_paths_generator))
```

Comment: Is there a way to input text to limit the list of mp3s?

Comment: You can grab a number with `n = int(input())`, then use that number to limit the number of mp3s displayed: `print(list(mp3_string_paths_generator)[:n])`. Is that what you wanted to do?